# What should I learn next?

Tags: calculus

I'm taking AP Calculus BC this year, so I decided to learn calculus a few days before class starts. So far, I've been able to solve all of the calculus problems wolfram alpha can generate for me, which includes the power rule, product, quotient, chain, integration by parts and integration by u-substitution. After that I learned how to integrate by using partial fractions. As a senior in high school not having started his class yet, I feel pretty confident that I've been able to conquer much of this year's material just in a couple of days. What should I look into learning next? BC calculus is only single variable. Matrices might be important, maybe parametric equations. Any expert advice?

Comment: Have you taken any calculus before this? Nice prep, by the way. I'd still warn you that it will be hard. But after this, multivariable would definitely help.

Comment: Just pre calculus, which only went over trig and limits and discontinuity.

Comment: Well, I'm entering AP Calc BC, too. The only difference between us is that a) I'm a junior and b) I took AP Calc AB last year. From what I've heard from classmates who've taken BC, though, I hear that you'll want to listen to what your teacher says - it will be a lot more informative than learning it on your own. By the way, the material you described sounds a lot like what we did last year.

Comment: I took Calculus BC in 11th grade. Matrices are not on Calculus BC. You need to know derivatives & integrals really well, optimization/related rates, solids of revolution, and for BC also some parametric, polar, Euler's method, but the biggest addition is sequences and series.

Comment: Get Barron's BC calc book.

Comment: Do you know how to derive all the rules you're using?  If not, I'd say learn to derive everything.

Comment: Go over the Theorems such as Squeeze, Intermediate, Mean Value, Rolle', FTC, etc.

Comment: Calc BC will do a lot of series and sequences. Try learning these perhaps. Calculus is much more than computing integrals and derivatives. Maybe look into their definitions and derive things from these.

Comment: You could go a different way and study abstract algebra. It requires no additional background, and you may enjoy it. I think Fraleigh's book is a good introduction.

Comment: You might want to look over some of the calculus references I gave in answer to the Mathematics Educators StackExchange question [Extremely “hard” books (or handouts) for undergrad studies](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3950/extremely-hard-books-or-handouts-for-undergrad-studies).